# Trying to Run Powershell from SQL Query Result

Tags: powershell

I am trying to see if we can store a Powershell command or line in a sql db and run it when retrieved.  Below is my code example:

```
$fields = "SELECT fieldName,exception,syntax FROM import_Fields WHERE HRISid='$srcID'"
            $results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $fields -ServerInstance $Global:sqlHost -Database $Global:sqlDB
            $fvalues = ""
            $values = ""
            $ct = $results.count
            Write-Host $ct
            $i = 1
            foreach($field in $results){
                if($i -lt $ct){
                    $fvalues += $field.fieldName+","
                    #Write-Host $field.exception
                    if($field.exception -eq "0"){
                        $name = $field.fieldName
                        $values += "'"+$row.$name+"'"
                    }else{
                        $name = $field.fieldName
                        $exception = $field.syntax
                        $values += "'"+$exception+"'"
                    }
                }else{
                    $fvalues += $field.fieldName
                    $values += "''"
                }
                $i++
            }
```

In the $values += "'"+$exception+"'" I want the result from a date conversion of "[DateTime]::ParseExact("+$row.LastHireDate+".Substring(0,10), 'yyyy-MM-dd', [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US'))" that i want done and is stored in the SQL db.  Is is possible to run this command?  I have tried it via Invoke-Command and Invoke-Expression.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? are you not able to execute command like `Invoke-Expression $Command` or  `iex $Command` where $Command = <Your PowerShell script or command>

Comment: When i try running the command it says the given string is invalid.  Here is the error message.

Invoke-Expression : Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At class_importdata.ps1:71 char:36
+                         $resultA = Invoke-Expression $exception
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Expression], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

Comment: Here is what the string looks like that i am putting into the Invoke-Expression:

[DateTime]::ParseExact('$row.LastHireDate', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz', [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')).tostring('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

Comment: Isn't this an sql injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following and got it to work.

```
$Converted = "[DateTime]::ParseExact('"+$date+"', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz', [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')).tostring('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
$dateConverted = Invoke-Expression $Converted
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what value you are passing in $row.LastHireDate but while calling `[DateTime]::ParseExact` function,
**the format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.**

following code snippet works without any issue. Adjust your script to match the input date format with second parameter in `ParseExact` function i.e. yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss

```
$Command = "[DateTime]::ParseExact('2020-01-0210:10:38', 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss', [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')).tostring('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
$dt = Invoke-Expression $Command
Write-Host "Output: $($dt.ToString())"
```

make changes to your script and give it try again.

---

> Don't forget to mark this as answered if this works for you.